# How do I filter what appears in a dropdown based on a wildcard search?

Tags: sql

I am working on a sql query like below. SearchName is a text input that does a wildcard search, and Family is a dropdown that has five options. This query is working just fine.

```
SELECT  SearchName, Family
FROM {0}
WHERE  (SearchName LIKE '%' + @0 + '%')
AND (Family = CASE WHEN @1 = '' THEN Family ELSE @1 END)
```

It queries the following table:

```
SearchName   Family
221ABC       A
221DEF       B
221XYZ       C
900ABC       D
900DEF       E
```

I have another query that limits (or should, but it doesn't) what shows up in the family dropdown based on what is in the SearchName field. For example, if I type 221 into the SearchName field, then I only want A, B, and C to show up in the family dropdown. When SearchName is blank, I want all five to show up.

```
SELECT Family
FROM {0}
WHERE
(SearchName = CASE WHEN @14 = '' THEN SearchName ELSE  '%' + @14 + '%'  END)
```

The above syntax works if I change SearchName to a dropdown and change the query to  `(SearchName = CASE WHEN @14 = '' THEN SearchName ELSE   @14  END)`. However, I need it to be a wildcard search. I'm not sure how to handle this.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your queries are invalid standard SQL). Please add the tag for the database product you are using

Comment: `WHERE @14 = '' OR SearchName LIKE '%' +@14 + '%'`